# java.security.AccessControlException trying to consume web services on Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, clojure, oauth, jvm

I'm trying to connect my Google App Engine webapp to the Google Latitude API using OAuth. I have it working in my dev environment, but when I try to test the app using Google's dev_appserver.sh, I get the following error:

```
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.net.SocketPermission www.googleapis.com resolve)
```

Is this an issue with the GAE Java class whitelist? If so, is there any way around this?

I'm pretty sure consuming OAuth services is possible on App Engine, after reading [this](http://otherfancystuff.blogspot.com/2010/09/using-oauth-with-spreadsheets-api-on.html) tutorial and others like it using GAE Python.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you give a snippet of how you're calling the Latitude API? It definitely looks like there's a class that's not whitelisted, see: http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/jrewhitelist.html

Comment: Thanks, Arthur. I looked more into this and it turns out that URLConnection is in the whitelist. I'm running into a related but different issue now, so I created a new question here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3817413/http-request-from-google-app-engine). So, how do I close this question?