# http request from Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, clojure, httpwebrequest, jvm, compojure

I'm trying to make http requests from my Google App Engine webapp, and discovered I have to use URLConnection since it's the only whitelisted class. The corresponding Clojure library is clojure.contrib.http.agent, and my code is as follows:

```
(defroutes example
  (GET "/" [] (http/string (http/http-agent "http://www.example.com")))
  (route/not-found "Page not found"))
```

This works fine in my development environment- the browser displays the text for example.com. But when I test it out with Google's development app server:

```
phrygian:example wei$ dev_appserver.sh war
2010-09-28 14:53:36.120 java[43845:903] [Java CocoaComponent compatibility mode]: Enabled
...
INFO: The server is running at http://localhost:8080/
```

It just hangs when I load the page. No error, or anything. Any idea what might be going on?

Comment: Does `http-agent` create threads? My understanding is that App Engine doesn't like those.

Comment: hmm good question. do you know if there's a non-threaded version of that?

Comment: You could try `http-connection` http://richhickey.github.com/clojure-contrib/http.connection-api.html, which seems to be quite a low-level wrapper around `HttpURLConnection`. Or just use `URLConnection`. I'll try to look at more options after lunch.

Comment: I added my comments as a proper answer, it was getting out of hand. I also added a few more possibilities for you to look into. Didn't have time to test any of them though :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`http-agent` creates threads so that might be why it does not work.

From the [API documentation](http://richhickey.github.com/clojure-contrib/http.agent-api.html#clojure.contrib.http.agent/http-agent):

> Creates (and immediately returns) an Agent representing an HTTP
>   request running in a new thread.

You could try [http-connection](http://richhickey.github.com/clojure-contrib/http.connection-api.html), which is a wrapper around HttpURLConnection, so this should work.

Another alternative is to try [clj-http](http://github.com/clj-sys/clj-http). The API seems to be a bit more high-level, but it uses [Apache HttpComponents](http://hc.apache.org/) which might be blacklisted.

I am guessing [http.async.client](http://github.com/neotyk/http.async.client) is a definite no-go due to its strong asynchronous approach.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try appengine.urlfetch/fetch from appengine-clj (http://github.com/r0man/appengine-clj, also in clojars)